# how to set fileupload dialog box to specified image folder path

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, dotnetnuke

is that possible to set the file open dialog to images folder specified path so when user select the fileupload it directly show the images and only specified extension and sizes images are shown in it
how can i validate it

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible and if you want to check the file size and format then check/ validate at the time of upload if not validate then generate error from code side.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in **window application** but it is not possible in **asp.net** application.

Explanation: As what ever you path will set(if possible) will be different to all the client.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: the question is **is that possible to set the file open dialog to images folder answer is no**.